# Python exception to represent a bug?

Tags: python, exception

I sometimes wish to raise an exception that will only occur if the code has a bug.  For example, suppose function `foo` is supposed to return an integer between 1 and 3.  Consider the following code:

```
switch = foo()  # Should be an integer between 1 and 3
if switch == 1:
    ...
elif switch == 2:
    ...
elif switch == 3:
    ...
else:
    # What goes here?
```

One possibility is something like `assert False, "foo() returned illegal value: %s"`.  Another option is `raise Bug("foo() returned illegal value: %s" % switch)`, for some appropriate exception class `Bug`.  Any thoughts on the best practice in this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No offense to @jonrsharpe :), but I don't particularly like the `ValueError` solution.

This is for two reasons:

1. Using the description he gave of a `ValueError`, the exception is raised when:

   > a built-in operation or function **receives** an argument that has the
   >   right type but an inappropriate value...

   Your function would be **returning** an inappropriate value, not receiving one.
2. A `ValueError` is for **working code** that receives an inappropriate value.  However, you said that you wanted to raise an error when a bug occurs.  Meaning, the code is broken.

I think a better solution is to raise the [`AssertionError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.AssertionError).  In my opinion, doing so is clearer because it is asserting (making sure) that the return value of `foo` is good.

However, I would implement it like this:

```
switch = foo()
assert switch in (1, 2, 3), "foo() returned illegal value: %s" % switch
if switch == 1:
    ...
elif switch == 2:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

As you can see, I put the assert-statement *before* the if-statements.  This brings attention to it and makes it clearer that we are protecting against a freak occurrence (a bug).

Answer (score 5):

You should `raise ValueError`. This is the exception for the situation where an unacceptable value is provided.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html):

> exception `ValueError`
>
> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as `IndexError`.

Comment: You'll note that in this case it is not a operator or function *argument* which has an illegal value, but a function *return value*, so this doesn't really fit.  The meaning I wish to express is more like a `SystemError`, but for my program, not the interpreter.

Comment: Shouldn't `foo()` `raise` its own error if it has a bug? The value is not an argument *per se*, but you receive it from the called function.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `assert` or raise an `AssertionError`.

An assertion is the app-level equivalent of SystemError. An assertion is exactly the idea that  your program has hit a bug.

Answer (score 1):

[You can create your own exception class](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) & then [`raise` it](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions). (It's perfectly fine to go with built-ins like jonrsharpe suggested)

```
switch = foo()  # Should be an integer between 1 and 3
if switch == 1:
    ...
elif switch == 2:
    ...
elif switch == 3:
    ...
else:
    raise ValueError("Oops! That was not a valid number. Try again...")
```

With your own `exception` class, it could look something like

```
class InputError(Error):
    """Exception raised for errors in the input.

    Attributes:
        msg  -- explanation of the error
    """

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

... # your code...
else:
    raise InputError("Oops! That was not a valid number. Try again...")
```

Needless to say, you have more control over your custom-defined Exception Class.

Comment: The "oops" message should probably be passed as an argument to the exception constructor: `raise ValueError("Oops! That was not a valid number. Try again...")`

Comment: Also, you suggest creating a custom exception class, but your example returns the built-in `ValueError`.  Confusing.

Comment: Lazy me. Not my regular SO day :/ Thanks.